# Simplest format to read/write huge files

Tags: java, file, encoding

I need to write huge files ( more than 1 million lines) and send the file to a different machine where I need to read it with a Java `BufferedReader`, one line at a time.

I was using indetned Json format but it turned out to be not very handy,
it requires too much coding and that consumes extra RAM/CPU.
I'm looking for something that looks like this:

```
client:id="1" name="jack" adress="House N°1\nCity N°3 \n Country 1" age="20"
client:id="2" name="alice" adress="House N°2\nCity N°5 \n Country 2" age="30"
vihecul:id="1" model="ford" hp="250" fuel="diesel"
vihecul:id="2" model="nisan" hp="190" fuel="diesel"
```

This way I can read the objects one at a time.

I know about url.encode & base64, but I'm trying to keep shorter readable lines.

So any suggestions please!

Comment: Why don't you use CSV ?

Comment: 'Not very handy' is not a problem description. 1 million lines is not huge. You can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`. Extra coding does not necessarily 'consume extra RAM/CPU'. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP i choose the BufferedReader because it's very fast as you said, i'm using it with Jackson library , but indented Json format makes the number of lines much bigger, i'm trying to optimize the code by reducing line numbers and disk in/out since the machines i'm using are not always the newest. that's why i'm trying to find a better solution

Comment: @MickaëlB need to read the lines into java objects, i don't know if there is a java library for that, i'll give it a look

Comment: `I need to read it with a Java BufferedReader, one line at a time`. Do you really need BufferedReader or you just said it because it is convenient to have one entry at one line and read line by line and loading whole file to memory is not an option? Can file by in binary format or it has to be human readable file?

Comment: @zakaria35 You should take a look to **BeanIO** (http://beanio.org/)

Comment: @Piro ,loading the file > 4GB in memory isn't an option on a 4GB RAM pc or less,so yes i need to read the file by lines, i choose the BufferedReader because it's the fastest reading way i found,for testing purposes i need it to be humane readable, but there is no probleme using binary a format if it's a better option

Answer (score 2):

With the huge files, any textual data formats, specially with the markup data like JSON, YAML or XML, is not a very nice solution.

I can suggest to use a universal binary format, like [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or [ASN1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One).

The Google Protocol Buffers is much easy to get started.

Of course if you just need a Java-To-Java data transferring, you can use java out of the box serialization.

Comment: OP has clearly stated he 'needs to read with a `BufferedReader`, one line at a time'.

Comment: @EJP Are there any guaranty that JSON, XML or YAML record can be read simply line by line without parsing ? I don't think so, the only possible format for BufferedReader.readLine - is comma separated values (CSV), and I don't think this is generally good idea to use it.

Comment: i'm a biggener with java and was out of ideas so i posted this question to gather suggestions so i can test them and choose the best for my program , i ll start testing CSV and Google Protocol Buffers then the binary format, thanks for the ideas

Answer (score 1):

What about reading/writing files in binary format using `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream`?

Of course, your data must have fixed structure, but as a benefit you'll get smaller file sizes and faster reading/writing.

Comment: If he needs to read with a `BufferedReader`, one line at a time, there is no apparent point in using a `DataOutputStream`, and there is definitely no point in using a `DataInputStream`, as the question is about producing output, insofar as it can be said to be about anything at all.

Comment: i need the file to be human readable for check/testing purposes, but since many suggested binary files i ll give it a look

Comment: however even for the binary i still need to read it line by line

Comment: @zakaria35 there are no lines in binary files. Consider them a sequence of primitives.

Comment: @ekaerovets that means the only way to work with binary files is loading the full content in memory ? . in that case binary won't work for me, thanks for the info

Comment: @zakaria35 not necessary, it's possible to process the whole file without loading it fully into memory

Comment: @ekaerovets in that case binary may work for me, i'll start learning about binary files in java,  

thanks

Comment: @zakaria35 besides, if you store your data in binary, they're way more compact. 1mil records may easily fit into RAM and will take less time to be sent to a remote machine

Comment: @ekaerovets i'v been trying binary files as you suggested, but i encountered an issue with memory saturated, could you please check [this  post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49533217/read-binary-file-with-a-buffer)