# Read binary file with a buffer

Tags: java, buffer, inputstream, binaryfiles

I'm  trying to read a binary file containing 100.000 different objects.
buffering a simple text file with the same content takes only 2MB with a *BufferedReader*.

But reading the binary files takes up to 700 MB and i get *OutOfMemory* error if I increase the number of objects to read.

So how to read the file and get the objects one by one without saturating the memory?

Here is the code I'm testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int i = 0;
    String path = "data/file.bin";
    InputStream file = new FileInputStream(path);
    InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);
    Object obj = null;
    while( ( obj = in.readObject() ) != null && i < 100000 ){
        String str =  obj.toString();
        System.out.println( str );
        i++;
    }

    timeTkken();
}

// Function to get the amount of time/memory used by the script
private static final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
private static final long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;
public static void timeTkken(){
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    long megabytes = memory / MEGABYTE;
    System.out.println("It took " + megabytes + "mb in " + ( (endTime - startTime) /1000 ) + "s ("+ memory + (" bytes in ") + (endTime - startTime) + " ms)");

}
```

Comment: what is original size of both files?

Comment: the binary file is 207 MB and the text version of the file is 232 MB on the disk

Comment: Do you have a possibility to change to a different dataformat than Java's serialization? It's not very useful, it's brittle and due to how it works on the inside it can keep a lot of things in memory (references to earlier serialized objects, which I suspect is the problem here) that you might not even need.

Comment: yes the issue is the stuf that it keeps in memory, are there are better alternatives to handle binary files in java ?

Comment: Why do you put `FileInputStream` inside `BufferedInputStream` and only then you create `ObjectInputStream`?

Comment: @AleksandrMukhalov to have buffering when reading the data. `FileInputStream` isn't buffered by default.

Comment: @zakaria35 you can use your own custom file format, but that's probably not very effective. You could consider JSON or XML, and compress them if it's the size of the file you're worrying about.

Comment: @AleksandrMukhalov as a beginner i didn't find a better way to do that , you have a better suggestion !

Comment: @Kayaman yes i was usinf a json format and it works fine with bufferedReader and Jackson library, but converting from json to java Objects takes extra time/memory, so i need to use binary to make the reading faster

Comment: How fast do you need it to be? If JSON isn't fast enough for you, you'd have to be working with something performance critical, but since you said you're a beginner it doesn't sound very likely. You could try something like [BSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON), protocol buffers or one of the many other binary protocols.

Comment: @Kayaman , i'm trying to get the fastest performance possible, using the json format is fast indeed, but it would be even faster if i can get Objects directly without the need to convert from json. the best thing a beginner can do is to learn , just need to be put on the right way, i ll give the BSON protocol a look

Comment: The worst thing a beginner can do is worry about performance. I see that in the questions all the time. A budding programmer is wondering if `i++` is faster than `++i`, wasting time on completely irrelevant things. Performance is an advanced issue, you shouldn't worry about it too much before you have a basic skill set and a wider understanding on how software works and where performance matters.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `ObjectInputStream` keeps all the objects in cache until the stream is closed. So if your binary file is ~207 MB, then real objects in java heap may easily take several GBs of RAM and they can't be garbage collected. Here the question appears: Do you need all of your data to be held in RAM simultaneously?

If no (you want to read an object, process it somehow, discard it and move to the next object), I would suggest using `DataInputStream` instead of `ObjectInputStream`. I don't know if this approach is applicable in your case since I don't know the structure of your data. If your data is a collection of records of the same structure, you may do the following:

```
    public class MyObject {
        private int age;
        private String name;

        public MyObject(int age, String name) {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("path.to.file")));
    // suppose that we store the total number of objects in the first 4 bytes of file
    int nObjects = in.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < nObjects; i++) {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject(in.readInt(), in.readUTF());
        // do some stuff with obj
    }
```

Comment: what you suggest here is almost what i need, i have to process 1 object at a time and get rid of any cache that may stay in RAM, my file contains a list of objects of different types, most of them are Lists  `Lists<MAP<StringString>>` . so if i can do `in.readObject()` without caching anything would be great, i ll try youre code

Comment: @zakaria35 You can't read one object at a time with `ObjectInputStream.readObject()' - you need to use DataInputStream, read raw primitives and strings and reconstruct your objects.